# Can I keep characters from ios to pc?

Tags: injustice-gods-among-us

If I buy the PC edition, would I be able to have my characters from my WBID account from ios on my pc version?

Answer (score 2):

According to [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/710163-injustice-gods-among-us/69558268) you should be able to do this.  As long as you sync the information on your WBID [on your current device] it will load up in the next system whether PC, Android, PS3 ect...

I hope this helps out!